# How to read bank account information within an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm writing an iPhone App these days, that would need to know the current amount of money available on a bank account, the user has to enter his/her details of course. I've read about HBCI (just need to cover german banks by now), but I can't find something pointing me in the right direction (as I don't know what to search for, I'm not surprised..)

As I said, I just need to cover german banks right now, and I just want the current amount of money. How would I do that? Is there something like openHBCI, that is still maintained and available for iOS? Any hint in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I would never enter my bank account credentials into an app that is not from my bank.

Comment: @onnoweb Well, this app is primarily for personal use, but there are other apps out there, that request the same thing, like outBank.

Answer (score 1):

That is a really heavy task .. you also need a database of the german banks with the access points and the hbci versions they accept.

a start point would probably be: http://openhbci.sourceforge.net/, or the successor of the library: http://www.aquamaniac.de/sites/aqbanking/index.php (german).

since it's c++ it should also work on the iphone/ipad

Comment: Thanks! I've found those two, too. Unfortunately openHBCI isn't maintained any more and AqBanking seems to need the shell to do it's magic. Well, I'm not a objC Noob, but I don't know how I would do that :/ I was hoping for a more.. "easy" to use.. API..

Comment: Did you find out any other solution yet?